# Компиляция Android приложения на Kotlin-е в терминале

Tags: java, android, kotlin, компиляция, терминал

Всем привет! Скажите, вот я научился компилировать android приложения в терминале (утилита aapt для компиляции R.java, jack.jar для компиляции java файлов в dex, снова aapt для сборки apk и подпись). А вот, допустим, в проекте есть и Java и Kotlin. Хм. Как в этом случае нужно компилировать?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще Kotlin предполагает что вы будете использовать maven или gradle и как туда встроиться подробно расписано тут:
https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Для Android скорее всего вам надо все делать на gradle, но есть варианты с

- Buck https://buckbuild.com/rule/kotlin_library.html
- Bazel https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin